# No error with Fail Save and show 302 post error... How To solve it?

Tags: laravel

[image: 302 image]

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Create New Expenses</h3>
        @if ($errors->any())
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
        @endif
      <form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('exp.store') }}" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Seller :</label>
        <input type="text" name="seller_name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('seller_name',isset($exp) ? $exp->seller_name : '') }}" placeholder="Seller">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date :</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" value="{{ old('date',isset($exp) ? $exp->date : '') }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Type :</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category" value="">
            <option value=""> Select Type </option>
            <option value="1"{{ isset($exp) ? ($exp->category == 1 ? 'selected' : '') : '' }}> Communication </option>
            <option value="2"{{ isset($exp) ? ($exp->category == 2 ? 'selected' : '') : '' }}> Transport </option>
            <option value="3"{{ isset($exp) ? ($exp->category == 3 ? 'selected' : '') : '' }}> Tools </option>
            <option value="4"{{ isset($exp) ? ($exp->category == 4 ? 'selected' : '') : '' }}> Raw Material </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Amount(RM) :</label>
        <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" value="{{ old('amount',isset($exp) ? $exp->amount : '') }}" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{ route('exp.index') }}">Cancel</a>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my saving data function

```
    public function store(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request, [
                'seller_name' => 'required|max:50',
                'date' => 'required',
                'category' => 'required',
                'amount' => 'required'
            ]);

            DB::beginTransaction();

            try{
                $exp = new Exp();
                $this->saveData($exp, $request);

                DB::commit();

                return redirect()->route('exp.index');
            } catch (\Exception $ex){
                DB::rollback();
                return back()->withInput()->withErrors('Fail to save.');
            }
        }
    private function saveData($exp, Request $request){
            $exp->seller_name = $request->input('seller_name');
            $exp->date = $request->input('date');
            $exp->category = $request->input('category');
            $exp->amount = $request->input('amount');
            $exp->save();
        }
```

This is my Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Exp extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exp';
    public $primaryKey = 'exp_id';
}
```

I'm new using this MVC .... i don't know why cant't saving but all my code look no error.

I try to find it but i find nothing ..

I need some help...

i already provide my view, controller and model

and below is my web.php

Route::get('/exp/create', 'ExpController@create')->name('exp.create');

Route::post('/exp/store', 'ExpController@store')->name('exp.store');

TQ.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to add mass assignment fields to your `Exp` model, hence the fields are not saved in your database. Add all the fields you want to be mass assigned to your model, and it should be working as expected:

```
protected $fillable = ['field_1', 'field_2', .... 'etc'];
```

Read more about this on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: after i add the fillable also same can't save

Comment: Are you sure that your code gets to your store() method in controller? Do some dd() on top and bottom of your method, to make sure your code executes completely.